# Understanding recursion in C

Tags: c, function, recursion

This is a recursive program. But I don't understand the sequence of events which take place during this program

```
#include<stdio.h>
count(int);
main() 
{
    int x=5;
    count(x);
}
count(int y)
{
    if(y>0)
    {
        count(--y);
        printf("%d ",y);
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
4 3 2 1 0 ...
```

But I don't get what happens when the first time `count(5)` is called and when count(4) is called. Does the control immediately go to the start of the function? Or first it prints the value of `y` and then again goes to the start of the function `count()`?

Comment: Try to use a debugger (on Linux that means `gdb` after having compiled with `gcc -Wall -g`), run the program step by step or at least with a breakpoint in `count`

Comment: are you asking that how the program is executing? Step-by-step??

Comment: @chris the program doesn't use `void main`; it uses assumed return `int`, which is pre-ISO (K&R) C.

Comment: yes i want learn the control sequences

Comment: @ecatmur, It was `void` when I posted.

Comment: The output of the above program should be "`0 1 2 3 4 `".

Comment: Your output appears to be incorrect; I believe the code as posted will output `0 1 2 3 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily step through the code to see what happened there, slightly edited code used :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void count(int);

int main() 
{
    int x=5;
    count(x);
}
void count(int y)
{
    if(y>0)
    {
        count(--y);
        printf("%d ",y);
    }
}
```

now see what happens during the execution. see the gdb session :

```
(gdb) b count
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4004ea: file rc.c, line 10.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, count (y=5) at rc.c:10
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, count (y=4) at rc.c:10
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, count (y=3) at rc.c:10
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, count (y=2) at rc.c:10
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, count (y=1) at rc.c:10
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, count (y=0) at rc.c:10
(gdb) bt
#0  count (y=0) at rc.c:10
#1  0x00000000004004fe in count (y=0) at rc.c:12
#2  0x00000000004004fe in count (y=1) at rc.c:12
#3  0x00000000004004fe in count (y=2) at rc.c:12
#4  0x00000000004004fe in count (y=3) at rc.c:12
#5  0x00000000004004fe in count (y=4) at rc.c:12
#6  0x00000000004004dd in main () at rc.c:6
(gdb)
```

The back trace speaks the whole history. See every call to count is "stacked". But none returned. And nothing printed yet.

Now see how they returned one by one :

```
(gdb) n
count (y=0) at rc.c:13 /* count(y = 0) returned first , it will not cause any printing*/
(gdb) n
(gdb) n
count (y=1) at rc.c:13 /* count(y = 1) returned second, this will cause printing 0 */
(gdb) n
(gdb) n
count (y=2) at rc.c:13 /* subsequent returns will cause printing of 1,2,3 etc */
(gdb) n
(gdb) n
count (y=3) at rc.c:13
(gdb) n
(gdb) n
count (y=4) at rc.c:13
(gdb) c
Continuing.
0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: suppose i have a `printf("wdf");` statement after `count(--y)`. then what happens ?

Comment: you will get a repeated print of "wdf".

Comment: when count(y = 0) will return to the place where it get called. It called by count(y = 1). So it will be returned to the instruction after the calling sequence, and will execute whatever there. In this case its a print statement.

Answer (score 5):

It is like a stack of dishes.

```
 1       2         3         4          5
                                      count(0)
                            count(1)  count(1)
                  count(2)  count(2)  count(2)
        count(3)  count(3)  count(3)  count(3)
main    main      main      main      main


count(0) prints nothing
```

go to step 4

```
count(1) prints 1
```

go to step 3

```
count(2) prints 2 ...
```

So to get the output of `4 3 2 1` you need to swap around the `count(--y)` and the `printf("%d",y)` lines.

Comment: if i swap the lines i will get 5 also

Comment: If you swap the lines, `printf` will be called _before_ `--y`. So `y` will still have the value of 5 when it is printed.

Comment: i just want to know when the function `count(--y)` is called ...does the control passes to the start of the function or it prints the vale of `y` ??

Comment: @AmolSingh it will go to the start of the function

Comment: @AmolSingh When the function is called, the code in the function is executed ... why or how could you expect anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's like an arithmetic progression.
That begin with **N > 0 and at each time substract one until reach 0**.
more on recursion here (use factorial example, and you will understand):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Hope this help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
void count(int y)
{
    if(y>0)
    {
        printf("%d ",--y);
        count(y);
    }
}
```

prints y-1, y-2, ... 0.

If `y <= 0`, then there is nothing to do. If `y > 0`, it decrements `y` prints the decremented `y` and then calls `count` with the decremented value of `y` to print the remaining values.

Another example, this:

```
void count(int y)
{
    if(y>0)
    {
        printf("%d ",--y);
        count(y);
        printf("amol");
    }
}
```

prints y-1, y-2, ... 0 amol...amol (y times).

It does so by printing y-1, then it recursively calls `count(y-1)` to print y-2, ..0, amol (y-1 times), then it prints the remaining "amol".

Comment: suppose after `count(y)` we have `printf("amol")` then how will be the output and why

Comment: @AmolSingh - what do you think?

Comment: @AmolSingh - no, compile and run the program, then try to understand it.

Comment: I fail to see how this is an answer to the question.

Comment: u are right the output is 4 3 2 1 0 amolamolamolamol but how the statement `printf("amol")` is exucuting ..?

Answer (score 0):

A program can be transformed by replacing things with their equivalents: variables with their values, function calls with the code of the function, conditionals on constants with selected code. e.g.,

```
main() 
{
    int x=5;
    count(x);
}
```

-->

```
main() 
{
    count(5);
}
```

-->

```
main() 
{
    if(5>0)
    {
        count(4);
        printf("%d ",4);
    }
}
```

-->

```
main() 
{
    count(4);
    printf("%d ",4);
}
```

-->

```
main() 
{
    if(4>0)
    {
        count(3);
        printf("%d ",3);
    }
    printf("%d ",4);
}
```

-->

```
main() 
{
    count(3);
    printf("%d ",3);
    printf("%d ",4);
}
```

--> ... -->

```
main() 
{
    count(0);
    printf("%d ",0);
    printf("%d ",1);
    printf("%d ",2);
    printf("%d ",3);
    printf("%d ",4);
}
```

-->

```
main() 
{
    if(0>0)
    {
        count(-1);
        printf("%d ",-1);
    }
    printf("%d ",0);
    printf("%d ",1);
    printf("%d ",2);
    printf("%d ",3);
    printf("%d ",4);
}
```

-->

```
main() 
{
    printf("%d ",0);
    printf("%d ",1);
    printf("%d ",2);
    printf("%d ",3);
    printf("%d ",4);
}
```

Comment: that was nice but what if the `printf` is after the `if` block?

Comment: @AmolSingh Please stop trolling SO.