# How does recursion work in this simple example?

Tags: c, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between the two locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552268/what-is-the-difference-between-the-two-locations)

> I asked this question yesterday also but couldn't get any answer previously.
>   I really want to know what is happening in the question step by step and the flow of control in this program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
rec(int);
main()
{
    int x=5;
    rec(x);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
rec(int y)
{    
    if (y>0)
    {
        rec(y-1);
        printf("%d ", y);
    }
    // printf("%d ", y)
}
```

> and how does the output vary in the two `printf` statements?

Comment: It is archaic code; it is using 'implicit `int`' declarations (which is not compliant with the current or previous versions of the C standard).  Somewhere, the output should include at least one newline.

Comment: See also (same questionner): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759397/what-is-recursion-really-and-explain-the-output-of-this-program (2012-08-01); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774409/understanding-recursion-in-c (2012-08-02); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552268/what-is-the-difference-between-the-two-locations (2012-09-23).

Comment: ya i even mentioned that i have asked this question

Comment: And you have three decent explanations.  What is the problem?  What don't you understand?

Comment: In the FAQ, under "What if I don’t get a good answer?" ... notice that it does not say "Ask the question several more times". That's aside from the fact that you got numerous good answers.

Answer (score 1):

rec is a recursive function that will call itself if condition is met.  So when it is called from main ( rec(5) ) the y is greater than 0 so it will call itself passing 4 as a parameter (y-1).  Once that call is done it will do printf , but because it passed 4 into itself it and 4 > 0 is true it will call itself again passing it 3.  That will continue until 0 is passed into rec .  When 0 is reached condition is not met and execution stops, so a previous call ( one when 1 was passed ) will do its printf, then a call before ( y =2) will execute its printf and so on! So your output will be
1 2 3 4 5

Edit:

I assumed your question was about recursion, not syntax

Comment: Note that this is the fourth time the OP has asked the same question, and has already received a number of good responses.

Comment: and what if the printf statement is outside the if

Comment: Then your output will include 0 if you only have the outside one! If you have both you will get 01122334455